# Conceptual clarity on JEP

Tags: java, parsing

I have a variable, whose value depends on other variables. This dependency is defined in the form of logical expressions.
For eg: If there is a variable A, in its datatype, the relation with other variables are mentioned. ie: A = (B&&C)||D

Now, this calls for expression parsing, and I have made use of [JEP](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/)( Java expression parser)

The values for B, C, D could be 4.0, 1.0 and 3.0. The value of A after the parsing would be 1.0.

Does this mean that the jep checks internally if the assigned value is greater than 0, and if its found above 0, then considers it to be 1?

```
String formula = "(B && C)||D";
JEP jep = new JEP();
jep.addVariable("B", 4.0);
jep.addVariable("C", 1.0);
jep.addVariable("D", 3.0);
jep.parseExpression(formula);
Number value = jep.getValue();
System.out.println("Value: " +value);




-------------------------------------
output:
Value: 1.0
```

Although the result of 1.0 is what I want, I do not understand how it happens internally.
When I do it on paper, I get the following

```
4 && 1 = 0100
         0001
--------------
         0000
||3      0011
---------------
         0011
So my paper method gives me 3.
```

What is happening internally? could anyone provide me insights?

Comment: I tried your expression in the JEP console, and it responds with true. Is it possible that 1.0 is some representation of true (and possibly 0.0 is false)?

Comment: yes that is what I suppose as well. What did you print out to get the boolean result?

Comment: (4.0 && 1.0)||3.0

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the JEP you are talking about here is Jep Java produced by Singular System Inc; http://www.singularsys.com/jep/

I trawled through the documentation for this and came to the conclusion that it is not really a Java (TM) expression parser.  Rather, it is implementing a "Java like" expression language.

(For instance, in *real* Java, `B`, `C` and `D` would have type `double` and `(B && C) && D` would be invalid ... since `&&` and `||` are only defined for `boolean` arguments.)

It appears that JEP treats numbers as truth values for `&&` and `||`, and (probably) for the results of relational operators `==`, `!=`, `<` and so on.  So `(B && C) || D)` in this case is computing `(true && true) || true)` which is `true` ... which is `1`.

Unfortunately, the documentation for JEP is rather sketchy.  I can't find anything in the documents on the JEP site that actually says how truth values are handled.

---

The other clue is that in (real) Java, the bitwise AND and OR operators are `&` and `|`.  Furthermore, JEP supports these operators, and others, in the "Bitwise Operator Table".

I suggest you change that expression to `(B & C) | D` ... and see if that gives you the result that you are expecting.

Comment: The change in expression produces wrong results ``` B|C ``` with B = 1, and C = 1, gives a result of 0.0

Comment: Well if that is what JEP is really doing, it makes no sense at all.  (To me ...)